# Grey Level Co-Occurrence Matrix // Python

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, glcm

I am trying to find the GLCM of an image using `greycomatrix` from *skimage* library. I am having issues with the selection of levels. Since it's an 8-bit image, the obvious selection should be 256; however, if I select values such as 8 (for the purpose of binning and to prevent sparse matrices from forming), I am getting errors.

QUESTIONS:

- Does anyone know why?
- Can anyone suggest any ideas of binning these values into a 8x8 matrix instead of a 256x256 one?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Help us help you

Comment: AssertionError: ... line 103, in greycomatrix assert image.max() < levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way for binning 8-bits images is to divide each value by 32. Then each pixel value is going to be in [0,8[.

Btw, more than avoiding sparse matrices (which are not really an issue), binning makes the GLCM more robust to noise.

Comment: No, it's difficult to say with the information you gave. It looks like that the image dimensions (image.max(), I supposed it the cooccurrence matrix) is smaller than the level you gave. I would check the matrix dimensions. Else, share the code and the complete error.